# Using query string parameter in custom html?

Tags: html, wordpress, query-string

Let say that in the blog editor I have a Custom html..

```
  <div>{blah}</div>
```

Is there a way to use a query string parameter inside this block .. in this case 'blah'

```
  https://your-site/page1/?blah=hello
```

i.e. the block should render as

```
  <div>hello</div>
```

---

Solved the problem, by parsing the QS in JS stored in Custom-html element.

It's a bit longer : [Adding Language/s IDE to WP](https://myriad.website/add-language-editor-to-wp/)

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use something like:

```php
$keyword = 'blah';
$markup = '<div>{blah}</div>'; // place your HTML markup here

$value = isset( $_GET[ $keyword ] ) ? $_GET[ $keyword ] : '';

echo str_replace( '{' . $keyword . '}', $value, $markup );
```

This will check if there's a parameter with the name `blah` in the URL of the page, and replace it with the value it holds. If it's not specified, it will simply be replaced with an empty string.

Comment: you mean i have to do changes somewhere in the php code ? I was thinking built in feature I can use in block editor ;)

Comment: I'm not aware of anything built in that could help you. You might need to add custom php code.